# How do you persist the installation on a Magento Docker container?

Tags: wordpress, bash, docker, magento, docker-compose

I am busy setting up a dockerized environment to develop PHP for Magento.
The image I am using is the following: alexcheng/magento2.
The git repository for this does contain an install script.
When I run "docker-compose up -d" everything works fine but I have to install Magento afresh each time the container goes down.

Any advice for how to deal with this? I am a relative newb at using docker but I can't imagine that you would have to reinstall it each time.

Note, I don't think this has to do with data persistence as a volume has been provisioned. When I include a line in the Dockerfile "RUN install-magento" I get the following error when building:

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘bash\r’: No such file or directory
    The command '/bin/sh -c install-magento' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm newbie about Docker as you. I suggest that you learn docker before wildly uses docker-compose tool. When we need data persistence the way is to use [docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).
Check if your docker-compose.yml have a volume section and if your user have permission on that path.